# Multiple properties are getting treated as separate arguments in mixins

Tags: less, less-mixins

I'm trying to write a mixin, but I can't seem to get the arguments working the way I want: multiple properties are getting treated each as a separate argument.

### Current Code

```
.transition(@property: all, @time: 1s, @timing: ease-in-out) {
    -moz-transition: @property @time @timing;
    -webkit-transition: @property @time @timing;
    -o-transition: @property @time @timing;
    transition: @property @time @timing;
}

a {
    .transition(color, opacity, .5s);
}
```

### Desired Output

```
a {
    -moz-transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-out; 
}
```

### Actual Output

```
a {
    -moz-transition: color opacity .5s;
    -webkit-transition: color opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: color opacity .5s;
    transition: color opacity .5s;  
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: dont forget to add a comma after @property in your mixin

Comment: see my answer for a clean solution based on LESS optional syntax for passing arguments to a mixin.

Comment: note that your desired output syntax is not what i believe you intend. the `transition` shorthand property must be a comma-separated list of complete single transitions. see  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'd suggest using LESS's escape function, i.e.:

```
a:link, a:visited { 
    color: green;
    opacity: .5;
    font-size: 1em;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 2em;
    .transition(e("font-size, color"));
}
```

And though it seems that LESS accepts that, it will only animate the last property in the comma-separated string you send through. A pity.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
It generates all the properties for me (only difference from your example is I put the transition mixin inside just "a").

Comment: Thanks Chris. Just ran in to this issue (multiple properties) and your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: I tried using the multi variable solution above, but because I am using wp-less to process in variables from WordPress theme settings it was throwing an error trying to evaluate the`@value: ~\`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')\`;` but this works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 25):

Using the solution found [here](http://www.toekneestuck.com/blog/2012/05/15/less-css-arguments-variable/) works with **one *AND* multiple** arguments:

```
.transition (@value1,@value2:X,...)
{
    @value: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')`;

    -webkit-transition: @value;
    -moz-transition: @value;
    -ms-transition: @value;
    -o-transition: @value;
    transition: @value;
}
```

Using it this way:

```
.transition(color, opacity .5s ease-in-out);
```

yields:

```
-webkit-transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-outt;
transition: color, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've been looking for something like this for awhile now! Can't say I understand it all (X is just a nonsense character to be stripped out later if it defaults?) but it works great.

Comment: I have trouble with this solution, it only works well if you use a comma. Without a comma the result is like this transition: all, 500ms ease-in-out, 100ms; For .transition(all 500ms ease-in-out 100ms)

Comment: @Robert: Just tried it in VS2013 with WebEssentials 2013, on lesstester.com and jsfiddle.net - all works as expected. See it working here: jsfiddle.net/dMk23  
Edit: It just happened to me too - after hitting "Tidy Up" in jsfiddle. The reformat adds **a space** right before `\sX/g` - and ***that* breaks it**. Check if that happend to you too.

Comment: It was my fault: I had not the same parameters, I had (...) instead of yours. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: sad that this won't compile with lessphp compiler

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pass a comma-separated list as an argument to mixin, you can simply **use a semicolon to separate arguments**.

Code below works as desired with the mixin you defined:

```
a {
    .transition(color, opacity; .5s);
}
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks. But not with customized functions like .transition-value(...) {transition: @arguments}

Answer (score 2):

Less mixins have the ability to use semicolon-separated arguments (as well as comma-separated). [They recommend you always use semicolons](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters).

If a semicolon is present in a list of arguments when the mixin is called, everything between semicolons will be considered as arguments, even if those things have commas in them. This allows you to pass a comma-separated list as *ONE* argument. If a semicolon is *NOT* present, it will treat commas as argument separators.

```
.transition(@property: all; @time: 1s; @timing: ease-in-out) { // NOTE THE SEMICOLONS
    transition: @property @time @timing;
}

a {
    .transition(color,opacity; .5s); // SEMICOLON AFTER 'opacity'
}
b {
    .transition(color,opacity, .5s); // COMMA INSTEAD
}
```

output:

```
a {
    transition: color,opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
b { 
    transition: color opacity .5s; // invalid syntax
}
```

Note that the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Formal_syntax) of the shorthand `transition` property must be a comma-separated list of single transitions. So `b` has an invalid value, and `a` has two transitions, in which the unspecified values default to their initial value:

1. `color 0s ease 0s`
2. `opacity .5s ease-in-out 0s`

This is likely not what you intended. (It looks like you wanted `color .5s ease-in-out 0s` and `opacity .5s ease-in-out 0s`.)

---

Now you might be wondering, "how do I pass a comma-separated list as a single argument, when there are no other arguments?" Simply append a dummy semicolon at the end of the list.

```
.transition(@property: all; @time: 1s; @timing: ease-in-out) {
    transition: @property @time @timing;
}

b {
    .transition(color,opacity;); // DUMMY SEMICOLON AFTER ARGUMENT
}
i {
    .transition(color,opacity); // MISSING SEMICOLON
}
```

output:

```
b {
    transition: color,opacity 1s ease-in-out; // 'color,opacity' is the first argument
}
i {
    transition: color opacity ease-in-out; // 'color' is 1st arg, 'opacity' is 2nd arg
}
```

Again, syntax for `i` is invalid, and `b` has two transitions:

1. `color 0s ease 0s`
2. `opacity 1s ease-in-out 0s`

Comment: Cool! I'm guessing it's a more recent feature.

Comment: @OscarBroman Depends on how you define "recent." It's been around since at least 2013; see Michael Ryback's answer.