# How to pass a comma-separated list to a mixin as a single argument

Tags: less

I made a multi-stop gradient mix-in that simply puts `@arguments` for all the vendor prefixes for `*-linear-gradient`. It works, put I'm annoyed when I define a gradient with many stops, I have to put **everything on one line** when using the mixin, like this:

```
.gradientMultiple(~'top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 16%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 36%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 66%, rgba(18, 34, 106, 1) 66%, rgba(13, 31, 136, 1) 84%');
```

I'd like to put the function parameter on multiple lines like this for readability, but it generates a parse error:

```
.gradientMultiple(~'top, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, 
    rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 16%, 
    rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 36%, 
    rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 66%, 
    rgba(18, 34, 106, 1) 66%, 
    rgba(13, 31, 136, 1) 84%
');
```

Here's the mixin definition:

```
.gradientMultiple ( ... ) {
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@arguments);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@arguments);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(@arguments);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(@arguments);
      background-image: linear-gradient(@arguments);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.gradientMultiple(top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)  0%,
    rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 16%,
    rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 36%,
    rgba(239, 239, 239, 1) 66%,
    rgba( 18,  34, 106, 1) 66%,
    rgba( 13,  31, 136, 1) 84%;);
```

Also see:

- [0](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters)
- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010520)
- [2](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1790)
- and finally the lead remark of [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068438/2712740)

Answer (score -1):

For [use cases](https://github.com/madebysource/lesshat#keyframes) when the mixin forces you to supply a string, *or* you don't want LESS to compute the argument value, you can use a bit of javascript:

(disclaimer: JS evaluation is now deprecated and possibly will be removed in LESS 3/4, so use this only when working with legacy code where no other alternative is available)

```
.keyframes(~`
    "translate, " +
    "50% { transform: translateX(calc(50% - 25px)) } " +
    "100% { transform: translateX(0px) } "
`);
```

Comment: See my answer above, the mixin takes *the only* argument not multiple. [Demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22foo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.gradient(top%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rgba(255%2C%20255%2C%20255%2C%201)%20%200%25%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rgba(%2018%2C%20%2034%2C%20106%2C%201)%2066%25%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rgba(%2013%2C%20%2031%2C%20136%2C%201)%2084%25%3B)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.gradient(%40value)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ctbackground-color%3A%20%40value%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: Besides, the OP is about splitting (escaped) _strings_.

Comment: That's actually the point, you don't need any *strings* or escaping for this use-case *at all*.

Comment: *See the edit* - you're trying to push an artificial example to justify the crappy-escaped-js hacks - there *are* certain rare/ege cases where you need the inline-js, but passing *any* args to mixins is not one of them (so you're just quickly running out of the scope of the Q).

Comment: For instance your edited snipped is done in normal Less [like this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.keyframes(highlight%2C%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%200%25%20%20%20%7Bbackground-color%3A%20transparent%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%2050%25%20%20%7Bbackground-color%3A%20red%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20100%25%20%7Bbackground-color%3A%20transparent%7D%5Cn%7D)%3B%5Cn%5Cn.keyframes(%40name%2C%20%40value)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40keyframes%20%40name%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40value()%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D) - no need for js-hacks as well.

Comment: For instance, no, __it isn't__ coz lesshat [keyframes](https://github.com/madebysource/lesshat/tree/master/mixins/keyframes) mixin doesn't allow that. Even if it did, there are still valid cases where you simply don't want LESS to calculate the result, and your editing the OP title to justify your innate anti-JS bias won't change that. I changed the expression nonetheless to make it less triggering to you.

Comment: *lesshat* - and what does all this have to do with lesshat at all? (For your reference `lesshat` was abandoned a while ago exactly because there's no need in its ugly hacks these days. So if you're still using it - wake up).

Comment: exactly nothing, so why do you insist on concrete examples instead of simply solving the problem which is to split the string. Let the developer decide what use case it'll be used for.

Comment: No, it's you missing the XY-problem here. I.e. instead of solving the problem itself you're pushing the hack to fix the issues of the wrong method the OP tried to solve his initial problem. *your innate anti-JS* - don't be ridiculous (and discover Less plugins to find the right way of using JS within Less. There *are* reasons the inine-js feature will be disabled by default in next major Less version - you are still free to using that yourself but be prepared to be criticized by others for pushing any ancient hacks).