# LESS transition mixin with prefixes

Tags: less

I was wondering if it's possible to create a LESS mixin that I could use like this:

```
.transform(transition, .5s, ease-out);
```

and has this CSS as output:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s ease-out;
transition: transform .5s ease-out;
```

but I would also be able to use the same mixin for other properties (i.e. `.transition(opacity, .5s)` should output to `-webkit-transition:opacity .5s; -moz-transition:opacity .5s; transition:opacity .5s;`

Thanks!

Leon

Comment: It is possible mate. I am pretty sure I saw a similar question earlier but can't trace it back now. But it would be better to use Prefix free or Auto-prefixer etc for this.

Comment: Here is the one I was referring to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061361/less-js-mixin-property-as-an-argument-of-another-mixin. You would also find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419741/less-css-mixins-with-variable-number-of-arguments/26190417#26190417) question useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Less version 2 you can use the autoprefix postprocessor plugin and the consensus is that you should use it for best practice.

The Less autoprefix plugin can be found at: https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix.

After installing the you can run:

```
echo "selector {transition: transform .5s ease-out;}" | lessc - --autoprefix="last 20 versions"
```

The preceding command outputs:

```
selector {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease-out;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s ease-out;
          transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

You should consider [Graceful degredation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degredation_versus_progressive_enhancement) and run the autoprefix plugin without any browser argument. (`lessc --autoprefix`). Then your output will look like that shown below:

```
selector {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out;
          transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

Notice that you can not use the auto prefix plugin when using less.js to compile your Less code in the browser. For client side compiling you can use the [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) library.