# Problems generating source map files with current Gulp setup

Tags: css, less, gulp, minify, source-maps

I have set up a `gulpfile.js` in my project. It's working pretty nicely mostly, except when it comes to generating source maps, especially for the `LESS` files it compiles to `CSS`.

I have put together a [gist](https://gist.github.com/alisamii/a3cd6809bc13686f8c29) which contains all the files in my gulp setup. Please note that other than the gulp file.js itself, all the other files are inside a directory called `tasks`.

The problems I am having are that

1. I had to disable the autoprefixer in development because the source maps that were being generated were invalid as the autoprefixer modified the original `CSS` file after the source maps were generated. To compensate, I have added mixins that add the vendor prefixes during development, and I have to disable those for development and enable the autoprefixer for the production environment.
2. I am unable to generate a minified CSS file at all if I want source maps. The minification breaks the source maps.
3. Although I have LiveReload set up, and the associated browser plugins, I cannot get the CSS to get auto-injected into the page as I am making changes.

If anyone can help me structure my gulp file.js to work more efficiently and more effectively, I would appreciate it.

Again, my `gulpfile.js` and associated tasks are in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/alisamii/a3cd6809bc13686f8c29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had to disable the autoprefixer in development because the source maps that were being generated

The docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer describe how to use the autoprefixer with gulp-sourcemaps:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(concat('all.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

The above create a new source map for all.css. So you should load the sourcemap generated by the less compiler first, see https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps#load-existing-source-maps

The docs of gulp-minify-css do not describe such an usage, but possible you can do:

```
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  gulp.src('./static/css/*.css')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(minifyCSS({keepBreaks:true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

Notice that in most cases you minify only your code for production. Development code, which has source maps should not have to be minified.

Since version 2 of Less you can use plugins for the Less compiler. Also gulp-less allows you to use these plugins (programmatic) see also http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-using-a-plugin-in-code

Documentation of gulp-less describes how to use the clean-css and autoprefix plugin at https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less#plugins. Notice that gulp-minify-css is leveraging clean-css's code too.

Also the usage of gulp-less with gulp-sourcemaps to create sourcemaps has been described at https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less#source-maps

So you should be able to use:

```
var LessPluginCleanCSS = require("less-plugin-clean-css"),
    cleancss = new LessPluginCleanCSS({advanced: true});

var LessPluginAutoPrefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    autoprefix= new LessPluginAutoPrefix({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]});


gulp.src('./less/**/*.less')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(less({
    plugins: [autoprefix, cleancss]
   }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
```

The above should generate the autoprefixed and minified CSS of your Less source, with CSS sourcemaps written into ./public/css/maps

Comment: unfortunately this syntax got obsolete(

Comment: Is the `gulp-sourcemaps` mentioned here (for css purposes) the same as this [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) (whose page only talks about javascript sourcemaps)?