# Convert rgba colour definition string in LESS to color instance

Tags: type-conversion, less, mixins

Suppose I've parsed my mixin parameters and colours are provided using `rgba` function.

Now I would like to mix two of those colours, but LESS `mix` function requires parameter instances of type `color`.

### What I tried

...and doesn't work

1. calling `color("rgba(0,0,0,.5)")`
2. `mix(@first, ~"@{second}")` where `@second` is a string like `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`

**How do I convert to color?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't find a built in function to do this in LESS.

The `color()` functions argument needs to be a hexadecimal or its shorthand representation.

But you can further **parse the string with javascript** to

- extract the individual r,g,b and alpha values,
- pass the individual values to the `rgba()` function to get a variable of type
  color.

You could do the first step in your original parsing.
If you need to do all in LESS you can do something like this:

```
  @color1: "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)";
  @color2: ~`@{color1}.replace(/^(rgb|rgba)\(/,'[').replace(/\)$/,']').replace(/\s/g,'')`;
  @color3: rgba(unit(`@{color2}[0]`),unit(`@{color2}[1]`),unit(`@{color2}[2]`),unit(`@{color2}[3]`));
```

Unfortunately the string can not be directly read into the `rgba()` or similar functions as they expect multiple arguments. Even with string escaping (eg. `~`) the output gets formated as a single variable (`~"a, b, c"` becomes `a, b, c` and acts as a single output string for the css), so we need to get each value individually and pass it to its respective argument/variable of the `rgba()` function. Using the function `unit()` we transform a string to a number that can be used further.

For example:

```
  @color4: mix(red,@color3);
  .test {
      color: @color4;
  }
```

resulting in **CSS**:

```
  .test{
    color: rgba(255, 64, 0, 0.75);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. This question was just part of the whole problem I had to solve. I also needed to parse arguments and decided in the end to simply mix two colours manually. You can read the [whole blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2013/03/less-gradient-mixin-with-fallback-for-ie.html) about it. If you have any further suggestions you can always comment on the post.